# how to use prettyface with jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, prettyfaces

I want rewrite URL of my project.

I am using primefaces. My  XHTML file like below

```
<ui:composition template="/html/Template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
          <h:form id="frmId">
             <p:inputtext value=#{bean.ajavaclass.variable} />
             <p:commandbutton value="check" action=#{bean.ajavaclass.fun1}/>               
           </h:form>
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My sessionscoped bean class

```
public class Bean implements Serializable{
 private AJavaClass ajavaclass=new AJavaClass();

getter and setter of ajavaclass obj...

}
```

My AJavaclass

```
public class AJavaClass implements Serializable{

      private String variable;

      public void fun1(){
        if(variable.equals('CODE')){
          fun2();
      }

    public void fun2(){

          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                        .redirect("./page2.xhtml");
      }

    }
```

this is working fine. if user enter CODE in textbox its redirecting to page2.xhtml.
but the url is `http://localhost:8080/projectname/page2.xhtml`

i want to hide the page name from the URL. how to do this using pretty faces.

i might wrongly configured pretty-config.xml, this is my configuration

```
<url-mapping id="CODE">
        <pattern value="/" />
        <view-id value="page2.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

but i need to know 
1.what i need to return from fun2?
2.fun2 is not directly handling the action operation is that a problem,if it is how could i   handle.
3.Or without pretty is there any ways in jsf or primefaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to use a leading slash in your view-id:

```
<url-mapping id="CODE">
    <pattern value="/" />
    <view-id value="/page2.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Using a view-id value of `page2.xhtml` will not be understood. It must be `/page2.xhtml`

Comment: it doesnt work if i provide it is not navigating to page2.xhtml

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: the above configuration not working, Do i need to return something from the method...

Comment: Yes. You need to return `/page2.xhtml?faces-redirect=true`

Comment: You could also return `org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.navigate.Navigate.to("/page2.xhtml");`